# Is it possible to place the value from the interpolation inside the formControl?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form with an input. I initially displayed the data in it using {{ }}. All the data displayed correctly. I had to extend the form and added a formControl to it, where I had to give an initial value inside so the value in the input is what is set in the formControl. Is it possible to put {{}} interpolations inside the formControl?

The input value before I created the formControl was underneath it as an interpolation.

{{item.price}}

html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
<input 
    [value]="item.price"
    id="price"
    formControlName="price"
/>
</div>
</form>
```

The formControl looks like:

```
export class MyFormControl {
  price = new FormControl<number>(0);
}
```

I would like the value of formControl to be what it was at the beginning when interpolation was used and not 0. Can I do something here like:

```
export class MyFormControl {
  price = new FormControl<number>(item.price);
}
```

Comment: If you have a FormControl and an input to mannage, the input **only** should have as attribute or formControlName or formControl. (forget value, checked, or anothers). The problem is that you have the formControl in a loop and you only have an unique FormControl, are you looking for FormArray?

Comment: My goal is to have the values in the input show as data from an array of elements, the formControl I need to edit these fields. And yes, the form is in a loop on this very array. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: [about formArrays -external link-](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a) [About idea general of formArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77616761/how-to-find-controls-in-a-form-which-has-deep-formarray-in-angular/77618295#77618295), [about a formArray of FormControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77234564/cant-get-angular-dynamic-nested-formarrays-to-work/77234648#77234648) [about a formArray of FormGroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915928/cannot-find-control-with-name-0-in-angular-reactive-form/76920797#76920797)